# ServiceStack DefaultRedirectPath not triggering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack in an MVC4, VS2012 project running on windows7.  I'm attempting to call a default "/search" route when the application loads.  To do this I have the following code in my AppHost Configure method

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());

SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
            DefaultRedirectPath = "/search"
        });
```

If I call this route directly (via /api/search) it works correctly.  However when I run my project I simply get a HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error.  It's appears to be attempting to locate a static source document from the website root (I've removed all of these) rather than the dynamic route specified in DefaultRedirectPath

I've also added a HttpHandler via the CatchAllHandlers method to see if the route is being attempted but it appears the DefaultRedirect is simply not happening.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  From everything I've read this should just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've set up your `/api` path correctly in web.config too.

`DefaultRedirectPath` is just a simple redirect used when you request the root of your API (i.e. "/api"). It literally returns a 302 with your `DefaultRedirectPath` as the `Location` header (combined with the application root URL, if your ASP.NET application isn't at the root of the server). In other words, it's not a "route", just a relative URL. And in your case, it will redirect to `/search` in the root of your application, not to `/api/search`.

It should work, if you use `DefaultRedirectPath = "/api/search"`.

However, when ServiceStack isn't at the root of the website, it will use `MetadataRedirectPath` first, and only if that is null or empty, `DefaultRedirectPath`. So you'll need to set `MetadataRedirectPath` to null, if this is what you want.

As for your test with CatchAllHandlers, as far as I can tell, CatchAllHandlers will actually *cause* your `DefaultRedirect` to not be used - the CatchAllHandler will be used as a handler, and the DefaultRedirectHandler that does the `DefaultRedirectPath` redirect won't ever come into play.

That will take care of redirecting **from "/api" to "/api/search"**.

MVC is in control of your root url - the "api" addition to web.config and AppHost.Config does exactly that - keep ServiceStack only in control of "/api", while letting MVC take care of the rest. So, with that setup, if you want a **redirect from "/" to "/api/search"**, you'd need to do it in the MVC home controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The web.config looks to be set up correctly for the /api path.  I have tried using /api/search (with and without the CatchAllHandler logic) but this did not work either.  As far as I can tell no redirect is being attempted at all from the website root which has me very frustrated.  If I manually navigate to /api I do get redirected but to api/metadata

Comment: I tried that too and it's still not working.  There appears to be a more fundamental problem - I think I'm missing something obvious.              SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
            {
                EnableFeatures = Feature.All
                                   .Remove(Feature.PredefinedRoutes)
                                   .Remove(Feature.Metadata),
                ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
                DefaultRedirectPath = "/api/search"
            });

Comment: Well, I'm getting uncertain of what you want to happen - because the way you're describing it, you have an MVC application, but you don't want MVC to handle the application root ("/") - it should redirect to the API? So to understand what you're doing: What are you using MVC for?

Comment: I'm adding Views to my services using http://razor.servicestack.net/.  So I want my root url to redirect to a ServiceStack service which will then render the associated view and template.  So I guess I'm replacing MVC - I did however begin with an MVC project and apply the ServiceStack packages to it.

Comment: Thanks Jimmi.  That makes perfect sense and is exactly what is happening.  I've evolved into a SPA but have not removed all the MVC parts.